# JQuery Datepicker has stopped working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using a jquery datepicker to display available booking dates for a reservation form.

The datepicker has been working fine, but now it now longer displays. Instead I get an error {*Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function*}.

The code is contained in the page header, and as far as I'm aware has been working fine until it just randomly wasn't anymore. I noticed the error just before as I was blocking a date on the calendar and it wouldn't appear when I went to test it.

The site is a Weebly site, and the form I'm using collects the entries for me to review. At 10:18pm last night (NZ Time) an entry was submitted with the correct date format, however the next booking (4:50pm NZ Time) was entered as "may 6th" which indicates it was typed by the user.

I am the only one with access to the source code for the site and have not made any changes in the last 2 months (Since I blocked some dates before Easter). I honestly have no idea why it would've stopped working.

*CODE*

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel = "stylesheet">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

      <!-- Javascript -->
      <script>

var dateToday = new Date();
var array = ["05/05/2017","06/05/2017"]
$( function() {$( "#input-806171099542486857" ).datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', date);
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day != 1 & day != 2) & array.indexOf(string) == -1 ];
}, minDate: dateToday
});
});

      </script>

</head>
```

Comment: Try adding https to jquery and jquery-ui links

Comment: check if you are not including jQuery more than once

Comment: It's working fine, just use https
https://jsfiddle.net/bfq6pLvc/

Comment: @PrashanthReddy Yeah, it's working in that fiddle, and it was working fine on the site until about 10:30pm last night (which according the the bookings coming in was the last time before people started typing the date into the text box themselves).

Comment: @DavorMlinaric Commenting out either reference in my header will either leave the error the same, or change it to JQuery is not referenced. Adding https didn't affect anything either.

Comment: In your original code, just check whether jquery-ui is included after jquery or not.

Comment: @PrashanthReddy Yeah, ui is one line below regular jquery. That hasn't changed either.

Comment: Try using cdns from this link... https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/ ..... or check your date field id. I see no conflict here

Answer (score 0):

Please check this. Your code is not working because of its blocking Http request over Https. I have modified it and it's working properly now.

```js
var dateToday = new Date();
var array = ["05/05/2017","06/05/2017"]
$( function() {$( "#input" ).datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', date);
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day != 1 & day != 2) & array.indexOf(string) == -1 ];
}, minDate: dateToday
});
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel = "stylesheet">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<input id="input" type="text" />


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have one working for multiple dates

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
 var array_names = ["John", "Joseph", "Luis"];
 var dbDate;
 var date2;
 var num = array_names.length;
 var array_dates =["1974-05-30", "1978-11-12", "1980-12-11"];
 for(var i = 0; i<num; i++){
  $("#share").append('<form id = "form_'+array_names[i]+'">');
   $("#form_"+array_names[i]).append('<input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="routename" value = "'+array_names[i]+'" id="name_'+array_names[i]+'">');  
   $("#form_"+array_names[i]).append('<input type="date" placeholder="Date of birth" name="date_birth" value = "'+array_dates[i]+'" id="datepiker_'+array_names[i]+'" class = "datepiker">');
   dbDate =  array_dates[i];
   date2 = new Date(dbDate);
   $("#datepiker_"+array_names[i]).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
   }).datepicker('setDate', date2)
 }
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <div id = "share">
    </div>
```

Here you have one working for a fixed number of dates

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
 var dbDate;
 var date2;
 var array_dates =["1974-05-30", "1978-11-12", "1980-12-11"];
  var num = array_dates.length;
 for(var i = 0; i<num; i++){
   dbDate =  array_dates[i];
   date2 = new Date(dbDate);
   $("#datepiker_"+i).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
   }).datepicker('setDate', date2)
 }
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <input type ="datepicker" id = "datepiker_0" value = "" class = "datepicker">
    <input type ="datepicker" id = "datepiker_1" value = "" class = "datepicker">
    <input type ="datepicker" id = "datepiker_2" value = "" class = "datepicker">
```